# Connect-AzAccount: Cannot bind parameter 'Credential'. Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I understand similar questions have been asked and answered before in stack over flow itself. But I have a slightly different requirement. My requirement is to log in to Azure using service principal and I am using the below PowerShell script for the same,

```
$azureAppId = "#######"
$azureAppIdPassword = "######"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $azureAppIdPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$azureAppCred = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($azureAppId, $userPassword))
 
$subscriptionId = '######'
$tenantId = '######'
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $azureAppCred
$containerId = Invoke-Expression -Command "docker run -d  -it  mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell"
docker exec $containerId pwsh -c  Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $azureAppCred
```

Above script fails with the error `Connect-AzAccount: Cannot bind parameter 'Credential'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential".` If I execute the above script without docker, it works just fine.

I tried to print the type of `$azureAppCred` using the command `docker exec $containerId pwsh -c Write-Host $azureAppCred` it prints `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` as expected but still the login command fails.

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong here?

Thanks,
Tintu

Comment: `docker` is an executable, meaning PowerShell can only pass string arguments to it - so it turns the credential object into the literal string "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" which `Connect-AzAccount` obviously can't use for anything. Not sure what the best option is here honestly... what's your motivation for running the AZ commandlets in a container rather than directly within the script?

Comment: We run the deployment on a common agent through docker using this method and kill the container at the end.  We follow similar pattern for other deployments as well like for eg Kunernetes using kubectl in similar fashion. It has been working great for us

Answer (score 0):

***As mentioned in this ***[`Docker Documentation`](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#log-into-azure)*** , the azure CLI login is different from docker azure cli login . As you are using service principal to connect with azure and run the docker run command, You can use something like below :***

```
$azureAppId = "#######"
$azureAppIdPassword = "######"
$tenantId = '######'
docker login azure --client-id $azureAppId --client-secret $azureAppIdPassword --tenant-id $tenantId
docker run -d  -it  mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell
```

Comment: Thanks but don't think what you are explaining me is what i am looking for. The purpose is different