# Az Powershell Connect-AzAccount fails in docker container, but works on host

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-powershell

**Problem**

I have a Windows 10 machine with Powershell 7.  I wrote the following logic to sign into azure using a service principle:

```
$Secure2 = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $AZ_DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT_ENCRYPTED_SECRET
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $AZ_DEPLOYMENT_CLIENT_ID, $Secure2
#Connect
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $AZ_TENANT_ID -Credential $Credential
Set-Azcontext -Subscription $AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -Tenant $AZ_TENANT_ID
```

It works fine on the host machine. However, when I try to run the same logic inside a docker image (dotnet sdk 6.0), the command fails with the error:

```
PS /builds> Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $AZ_TENANT_ID -Credential $Credential
WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( /root/.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate protections.
Connect-AzAccount: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app '{guid}'.
Trace ID: asdfasdf
Correlation ID: asdfasdf
Timestamp: 2022-04-19 15:07:22Z
```

**Az Powershell Versions**

On the host, I'm running:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-InstalledModule -Name Az


Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
7.1.0                Az                                  PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in Azure. This module is compatible with PowerShell and Window…
```

Inside the container:

```
PS /builds>  Get-InstalledModule -Name Az

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
7.4.0                Az                                  PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in Azure. This module is compatible with PowerShell and Windows PowerShell.…
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install vim -y
COPY . /builds
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
```

Then I manually ran this command to install the az module:

```
 pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force"
 pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity -AllowPrerelease PSGallery -Force"
```

**EDIT 1**

In my Dockerfile, now I'm using multiple stages now so I don't have to install the Azure Powershell toolset inside the dotnet SDK image.
Now my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM --platform=amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS deployFunctionApp
RUN apt update && apt-get install vim -y
COPY . /builds
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
RUN apt-get install curl && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
WORKDIR ./builds/tests
RUN dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\TestResults\test-results.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
WORKDIR ../
RUN cat ./externalVariables.json
RUN pwsh -c "./deploy-function-app.ps1"

FROM --platform=amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell:7.4.0-ubuntu-18.04 AS deployAppRegistration
COPY . /builds
WORKDIR ./builds
RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity -AllowPrerelease -Repository PSGallery -Force"
RUN pwsh -c "./ad-app-reg.ps1"
```

So now I can build in stages like this:

```
PS /Users/me> docker build --target deployAppRegistration -t mytest .

[+] Building 17.5s (7/9)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.35kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell:7.4.0-ubuntu-18.04                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 23.03kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [deployappregistration 1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell:7.4.0-ubuntu-18.04@sha256:4d2a4c73e91c27be3ac3de40a1dd8cf36dde17d43da8837a1967fab6ac376950                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [deployappregistration 2/5] COPY . /builds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => [deployappregistration 3/5] WORKDIR ./builds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [deployappregistration 4/5] RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity -AllowPrerelease -Repository PSGallery -Force"        
=> [deployappregistration 5/5] RUN pwsh -c "./ad-app-reg.ps1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                           16.1s
```

But it fails to connect to azure still.  I start a fresh container based on this image, and can recreate the error i see in the docker build command:

```
root@7a0f9c69306d:/builds# ls
arm_templates            deploy-function-app.ps1  externalVariables.json  src
Dockerfile            postman_tests           tests
ad-app-reg.ps1     docs                  README.md

root@7a0f9c69306d:/builds# pwsh
PowerShell 7.2.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /builds> ./ad-app-reg.ps1
WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( /root/.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate protections.
Connect-AzAccount: /builds/ad-app-reg.ps1:30
Line |
  30 |  Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $AZ_TENANT_I …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application
     | registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret
     | value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app '[ad app reg guid]'. Trace ID: asdfasdf Correlation ID: asdf Timestamp:
     | 2022-04-25 12:42:08Z

Set-AzContext: /builds/ad-app-reg.ps1:32
Line |
  32 |  Set-Azcontext -Subscription $AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -Tenant $c …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Run Connect-AzAccount to login.
```

Comment: Do you have any extra tenant ,If yes please try to remove those tenants and run the following to see if still facing the same `Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication` and also please check the module if its properly installed or not.

Comment: https://dev.to/omiossec/getting-started-with-azure-powershell-docker-image-and-github-actions-1g7

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT so when I use the device authentication, it works.  which would prove the install is fine, I think right?

Comment: Yes, also you can use Get-modules to check if all the required modules has installed or not. May i know if you can use the service principal in this way `$azureAppId = "#######"
$azureAppIdPassword = "######"
$tenantId = '######'
docker login azure --client-id $azureAppId --client-secret $azureAppIdPassword --tenant-id $tenantId
docker run -d  -it  mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell`

Comment: AFAIK,The way we are trying in windows we can not do the same in docker

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT no ... I'm using the sample code I posted above.  creating a secret ... and then encrypting it.  I save that to a file.  and then create credentials using the client id and the encrypted secret.  does that make sense?

Comment: It seems like @Mathias R. Jessen mentioned the same thing what i wanted to elaborate. [here is the SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035505/connect-azaccount-cannot-bind-parameter-credential-cannot-convert-the-syste)

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I could be way off - still working on coffee number one, but I really don't think the two are comparable right?  Cuz I'm copying a powershell script over to a container that has the azure powershell module installed... and i'm just trying to RUN the powershell command.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT the error message I'm getting is different from the other poster as well.  I'm getting the error that the client secret is invalid, whereas their error is about binding.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I just manually recreated the encrypted secret on the docker container - reusing the same client ID and secret ... and it works.  So basically, the issue is that the value I created on my HOST machine for the encrypted secret is not working on the docker container.  will poke around more and post a new question if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I had to recreate the encrypted secret in the container and then it started to work.  It's still not clear why it didn't like the encrypted secret that I created on the host and saved to a file.
It was created using the same secret and security principle.
But I guess the error message was legit - it really didn't like the credential!